# How do to store variables which are strings in python and pass them around in functions?

Tags: python

**I have a problem where i get an error message telling me its used before its assigned. I am not sure how to pass around the variable result and answer in my code. 
The problem is that i am creating a shift cypher.**

These are the instructions:

*Complete the encode method so that it returns the encoded message.
Complete the decode method so that it returns the decoded message.
In the main method, 
      - prompt the user for the message.
      - prompt the user for the shift amount.

      - Print the message.

      - Call encode with the message and the shift amount.

      - Store the encoded message returned from encode.

      - Print the encoded message.

      - Send the encoded message and the shift amount to the decode method.

      - Print the decoded message.*

```
def encode(s, shiftamount):
  for x in range(0, len(s)):

    if s[x] == " ":
      print(" ", end="")

    if s[x] in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
      if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) > 'Z' : 
        result += chr(ord(s[x]) + (shiftamount - 26)) 

      if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) <= 'Z' :
        result += chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount)

    if s[x] in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
      if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) > 'z' : 
        result += chr(ord(s[x]) + (shiftamount - 26)) 

      if chr(ord( s[x] ) + shiftamount) <= 'z' :
        result += chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount)
  return result

def decode(s, shiftamount):

  for y in range(0, len(s)):

    if s[y] == " ":
      print(" ", end="")

    if s[y] in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
      if chr(ord(s[y]) + shiftamount) > 'Z' : 
        answer += chr(ord(s[y]) - (shiftamount - 26)) 

      if chr(ord(s[y]) + shiftamount) <= 'Z' :
        answer += chr(ord(s[y]) - shiftamount)

    if s[y] in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
      if chr(ord(s[y]) + shiftamount) > 'z' : 
        answer += chr(ord(s[y]) - (shiftamount - 26)) 

      if chr(ord( s[y] ) + shiftamount) <= 'z' :
        answer += chr(ord(s[y]) - shiftamount)
  return answer


def main():
  s = input("Enter the message:")
  shiftamount = int(input("Enter the shift:"))
  print(s)
  encode(s,shiftamount)
  decode(s,shiftamount)
  print(result)
  print(answer)


########################################################################
###                Do not modify anything below here                 ###
########################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Comment: *an error message telling me its used before its assigned* - you may think the details of this error message aren't important enough to read carefully, but they are. An error message telling you **what** is used before it's assigned?

Comment: After you've identified *what* it is the error message says is being used before it's assigned, go back and find the place in the function where you're assigning it an initial value, invoked during function execution before the place where the error takes place. If there is no such place where an initial value is assigned, then you know what you need to change.

Comment: Its telling me that the encode function was using result before it was assigned. I understand what that means but i didnt know how to fix it. I was told to use result = "" which solved that issue but now the problem is that result and answer are missing in the MAIN function. I placed result,answer in between the main brackets so it can bring this result to the MAIN function but that doesnt work.

Comment: Do you know what those `return` statements are for in `encode` and `decode`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that is what i did but i didnt know what exactly i need to write so that i can initially assign it to something. if that makes sense. The line result = "" fixed that problem, someone recommended me that. Does that fix it because it initially assigns it as a string? can you explain that please?

Comment: @Seb i believe the return statements are for returning a value from the encode or decode functions to where it was initially called from.

Comment: Correct. So you should try to capture those returned values somewhere, right?

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the result and answer variables before using += operation, also in main you need to assign it to a local variable before printing.

Lines: 52,53,25,2

```
def encode(s, shiftamount):
  result=''
  for x in range(0, len(s)):

    if s[x] == " ":
      print(" ", end="")

    if s[x] in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
      if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) > 'Z' : 
        result += chr(ord(s[x]) + (shiftamount - 26)) 

      if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) <= 'Z' :
        result += chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount)

    if s[x] in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
      if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) > 'z' : 
        result += chr(ord(s[x]) + (shiftamount - 26)) 

      if chr(ord( s[x] ) + shiftamount) <= 'z' :
        result += chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount)
  return result

def decode(s, shiftamount):

  answer=''

  for y in range(0, len(s)):

    if s[y] == " ":
      print(" ", end="")

    if s[y] in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
      if chr(ord(s[y]) + shiftamount) > 'Z' : 
        answer += chr(ord(s[y]) - (shiftamount - 26)) 

      if chr(ord(s[y]) + shiftamount) <= 'Z' :
        answer += chr(ord(s[y]) - shiftamount)

    if s[y] in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
      if chr(ord(s[y]) + shiftamount) > 'z' : 
        answer += chr(ord(s[y]) - (shiftamount - 26)) 

      if chr(ord( s[y] ) + shiftamount) <= 'z' :
        answer += chr(ord(s[y]) - shiftamount)
  return answer


def main():
  s = input("Enter the message:")
  shiftamount = int(input("Enter the shift:"))
  print(s)
  result=encode(s,shiftamount)
  answer=decode(s,shiftamount)
  print(result)
  print(answer)


########################################################################
###                Do not modify anything below here                 ###
########################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Comment: thank you. I have seen the same  ' result=encode(s,shiftamount)' way of doing this on youtube i just didnt know how to properly implement it.

Comment: could you help me fix my spacing in the output. Here is my finished code:

Comment: Output i need

        'Enter the message: Hello World
        Enter the shift: 10
        Hello World
        Rovvy Gybvn
        Hello World '
**Out put i get**

        'Enter the message:  Hello World
        Enter the shift:  10
        Hello World
         RovvyGybvn
        HelloWorld'

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def main():
  s = input("Enter the message:")
  shiftamount = int(input("Enter the shift:"))
  print(s)
  e = encode(s,shiftamount)
  d = decode(s,shiftamount)
  print(e)
  print(d)
```

you need to create reference, and instantiate it